# Saving multiple Arraylists in File

Tags: android, file, arraylist

I've tried to get my head around this, but can't so asking the forum. Does anyone think it would be possible to save multiple ArrayLists to a file? Would I have to create multiple files for each List or could I bung them all in one with a reference of some sort? So far I have knocked up a quick experiment but to no avail. (this is just a quick representation of my code but I am away from the computer)

```
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(Ing);
    oos.writeObject(IngN);
    oos.writeObject(Step);

    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best to serialize the arraylists to something like json first, and then write that to a file.

You could create a simple class that holds 2 arraylists, and then serialize that class so you end up with one string that contains both arraylists, which you can write to one file.

For serializing to json, check out [jackson mapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

I'm not sure what your use case is, but you may want to also look into saving the data into a database instead of a file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't want to get into databases and Json as I'm fairly new to this as it is. But I guess it's time to start learning more. I want to store three values, consisting of ingredient quantities and names which can be as a pair, and also recipe steps which can be on their own. I want to be able to call back these values and then programmatically set up TextViews in a LinearLayout. Do you know of any tutorials or online help which may be of assistance?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at http://www.activeandroid.com/. It's very simple especially for a beginner. 
For storing recipes, you could get quite complex and have multiple tables etc, but for starting off, I recommend just using one table.

Store your ingredients pair as a string. So write a small function that takes the pair and converts it to a comma separated string.

That way your recipe object just has 2 string fields - ingredients, and steps, and it will be really easy to store that in a database with active android.

You will need to convert the ingredient string back into a pair.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds very do-able, I'm going to look at Json first but I'll definitely give Active Android a go! Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the very nooby question but I haven't needed to do this before. How do I add the add-on to eclipse?, Looked everywhere but I don't know the correct terminology. Is it an add-on? or existing project or what? User library?

Comment: You should clone the library from Github (https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid), use the git clone command.

Then import that library into eclipse with the File -> Import -> Existing Android Code.

Make sure the project is marked as a library in the Properties -> Android tab. Then add that library as a dependency to your project in the same place (but looking at your project properties instead).

Comment: I couldn't get the ActiveAndroid import to work so I think serialization toa  file is going to be my best (and most understandable) option. I created a method that links together the Ingredient quantities and respective Names separated by a comma, and now working on a way to place both the Ingredients and steps into a file. Thanks for all your help!